# interface object couldn't extends Record<string, unknown>

Tags: typescript

why interface couldn't extend `Record`

```
interface Data {
  a: string
}

Data extends Record<string, unknown> ? 'yes' : 'no' // 'no'
```

however, if I change the Data to type it works fine

```
type Data {
  a: string
}
 
Data extends Record<string, unknown> ? 'yes' : 'no' // 'yes'
```

Comment: :) Strange behavior. Even if you replace ```Data``` interface in conditional with ```DataAsType``` which will be: ```type DataGeneric<T> = T; type DataAsType = DataGeneric<Data>;``` result will be the same. But if you replace ```Data``` with this ```{[key in keyof Data]: Data[key]}``` it will give ```yes```.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`type T = Record<string, unknown>`   evaluates to  `{ [x: string]: unknown; }`

Object types have an [implicit index signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029), but interfaces don't ([for safety reasons](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024)), so they don't extend an index type.