# TypeScript Generics with interface parameters

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm playing around with TypeScript generics and am a bit confused.

I'm basically trying to create an interface that has a method that can receive an arbitrary options parameter. This parameter can be any object. What the exact object looks like is determined by the implementing class.

```js
interface MyOptions {
    foo: string
}

interface TestInterface {
    doSome<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(value: T): void
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {
    doSome<T = MyOptions>(value: T): void {
        value.foo // complains that foo doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, but when I try to access `value.foo`, it looks like `value` isn't typed.

Am I doing something wrong?

#### UPDATE

I found some useful stuff regarding interfaces not extending `Record<string, unknown>`, saying to use a `type` instead (see [interface object couldn't extends Record<string, unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64621451/interface-object-couldnt-extends-recordstring-unknown)).

However, after updating the snippet above as shown below, the issue remains.

```js
type MyOptions = {
    foo: string
}

interface TestInterface {
    doSome<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(value: T): void
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {
    doSome<T = MyOptions>(value: T): void {
        value.foo // complains that foo doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAdrPN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That approach works, but the actual interface I'm working on will have multiple methods that receive different types of parameters. This could be solved like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAHMwD2IAzsgN4BQyVyM++AXMkWFKAObkC+55oksiFBkxgAFtBx5CJCtWQAjOFEbNWIDt17ho8JMgAqEZgEltApAB59yCAA9IIACYl88gFYQEYADTIAqjb2EE4u7p5gAHxklNSO+ADK+AC2EAAUAG5wADYArhCM+gCUjOn4wI4xVHGJKWLAbACiWURpmbn5-sXIpeVcPAhZcEQkhswAwoPDyMBJ2FkQKeAjRmCm-LoQFsK4BMS+wmISO9JRsrEJya3ZeYzbUsRdPY7RcnJteQB0tPiVyJqv1UudUazSu7VuWEOUEkuyIjzKzzOr261wgH0UUF+3E4QA),  but it's not as explicit.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I want is possible though. Maybe that approach is the way to go indeed ;)

Comment: Happy to accept your answer if you write one up and my idea turns out to be impossible by the way @jcalz!

Comment: What "idea" are you talking about?  The code you wrote doesn't have the effect you're looking for; by having the type parameter on the method signature instead of the interface, you're saying that the *caller* chooses the type argument, not the implementer.  That doesn't match with your goal.  Am I missing something about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not that familiar with generics. I wasn't aware that this lets the *caller* choose the type. I thought that by declaring `T = MyOptions`, I (the *implementer*) am choosing the type. Again, happy to accept.

Comment: No, that's just a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an important difference between [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *call signatures* and generic *types*.  A generic call signature has the generic type parameters on the call signature itself, like this:

```
interface TestInterfaceOrig {
    doSome<T extends object>(value: T): void
}
```

When you have a generic call signature, the *caller* gets to specify the type argument:

```
declare const testInterfaceOrig: TestInterfaceOrig;
testInterfaceOrig.doSome<{ a: string, b: number }>({ a: "", b: 0 });
testInterfaceOrig.doSome({ a: "", b: 0 });
```

In the above, the caller is able to choose that `T` is `{a: string, b: number}` in both calls.  In the second call, the compiler *infers* that type from the `value` argument, but it's the same... the caller is in charge.  The implementer, on the other hand, has to write `doSome()` so that it works for any `T` the caller chooses:

```
const testInterfaceOrig: TestInterfaceOrig = {
    doSome<T extends object>(value: T) {
        console.log(value); // ‍♂️ there's not much I can do, 
        // all I know is that value is an object
    }
}
```

It doesn't help or change anything for the implementer to choose a [type argument default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), since defaults don't constrain the input in any way.

```
const testInterfaceOrig: TestInterfaceOrig = {
    doSome<T extends object = MyOptions>(value: T) {
        console.log(value); // ‍♂️ still the same
    }
}
```

If the implementer tries to actually constrain the input, there is an error... the caller chooses, not the implementer:

```
const testInterfaceOrigNope: TestInterfaceOrig = {
    doSome<T extends MyOptions>(value: T) { // error!
        console.log(value.foo);
    }
}
```

This isn't what you're looking for, so you can't write it this way.

---

On the other hand, a generic type has the generic type parameters as part of the type declaration, like this:

```
interface TestInterface<T extends object> {
    doSome(value: T): void
}
```

Here, there is no `TestInterface` type by itself (although you can set defaults here too, but let's not digress).  You can't have a value of type `TestInterface`.  Instead, you can have a value of type `TestInterface<{a: string, b: number}>`, or `TestInterface<MyOptions>`, or `TestInterface<T>` for some object type `T`.  And once you have a value of that type, the `doSome()` method can only accept values of type `T`.  The call signature is not generic; the caller is unable to choose `T` here.  The choice of `T` is made by whoever supplies the `TestInterface<T>` instance:

```
class TestClass implements TestInterface<MyOptions> {
    doSome(value: MyOptions): void {
        value.foo
    }
}
```

So here `TestClass` implements `TestInterface<MyOptions>`.  The `doSome()` method only accepts `MyOptions`.  That means the compiler knows that `value` has a `foo` property.  And so the caller is not in charge of `T` at all, as desired:

```
const tc = new TestClass();
tc.doSome({ foo: "abc" }); // okay
tc.doSome({ a: "", b: 0 }); // error, that's not a MyOptions.
tc.doSome<{ a: string, b: number }>({ a: "", b: 0 }); // error, doSome is not generic
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFkCeB5ADhEAezAGdUBvYVa1OQwgLlRIhnAHNgBfUSWRFKgAqUFgEk+8ZFGxt2FKjQAmhAMqEAtlAA8Q1FAAe0MErKEARgCsoSCAD4AFADcEAGwCuUJkICUTJ4QgStzAwEjELKjQ4pICMnLeohAS0FIosiDyALwKNKgq6lq6+kZQJmZWNhCoOVh4BBGOLh5ewj65eTThpISuUAB0roTszm6ePgDcitQ8PGER1dHJsdIZ7AByhLitIjGpcWs1HdQFmjp6hsamGDj4RKRNYzvt5KgA9G-6MDCEMACE0063RIvQGQxGzU8-TohEmgNmoWASxS-FWcn6pyKrwQTBYbDA7AANKhzEwwO4NOZYKguI5sUwAEQM4mk1AABhpcORK3S6MxUAc9NQTJZTA5XDhiNC4H20mESRRaXOJSuFWstjsx3yajOoxa3j8qACQRCYVcCBIZF2EAAwubLagQBpcH0tJArQqeTo6ndGlr+XrPEwfQ1SIbjUotXlIQMYfDTcDFkgjmAoAB3eUsO0WkgOLlIDE6rSC2j0RkIcxIBmcibvT6EADWCEwSILAaFIpJYprda+P3+rcLhR0QrxHFFqHJlOptJLOOFzK77J7Hz7vwBwCAA)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload the function in that way. If you are trying to create a union for this, then you can use the following code example:

```js
type MyOptions = Record<string, unknown> & { foo: string };

interface TestInterface {
  doSome<T extends MyOptions>(value: T): void;
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {
  doSome<T extends MyOptions>(value: T): void {
    console.log(value.foo);
  }
}

const test = new TestClass();

test.doSome({ foo: "bar", baz: "qux" });

/*
*  The combined type of the two objects is:
* TestClass.doSome<{
    foo: string;
    baz: string;
}>(     value: {foo: string, baz: string}): void
* 
* */
```

Useful link for Dos & Don'ts for overloading [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#overloads-and-callbacks)

**UPDATE**

I believe I understand what you are looking for; the issue you are running into is that Typescript does not know what properties of T are within your function or class. The compiler could not prove that the `foo` property is on every type. You have two options, either add a primitive type to the argument or apply a generic constraint through the `extends` keyword:

```js
type MyOptions = {
  foo: string;
};

type MyOtherOptions = {
  bar: string;
};

interface TestInterface {
  doSome(value: unknown): void;
}

class TestClass<T extends Record<string, unknown>> implements TestInterface {
  doSome = (value: T): void => {
    console.log(value.foo);
  };
}

const test = new TestClass<MyOtherOptions>();
test.doSome({ bar: "baz" });

const test2 = new TestClass<MyOptions>();
test2.doSome({ foo: "bar" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wasn't looking for a union type. I probably phrased my question in the wrong way. See the comments below my question.